# ssh: not setting $PATH when passing commands via EOL?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh

I have a deploy script that I want to run from a remote server, if I connect to the server and command manually it works fine:

```
ssh root@server
cd /some-deploy-folder
node do-something.js
```

But if I try to do the same by passing it into a single command to ssh:

```
ssh -t root@localhost <<EOF
  cd /some-deploy-folder
  node do-something.js     
  exit
EOF
```

Bash is unable to find the `node` command reporting `node: command not found`

Is there some reason that passing the `EOL` commands directly into `ssh` is not correctly setting up the environment?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you send the command and not directly being logged in the shell is a non-interactive one and you don't have the same environment, you can read more about this on:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/698957/ssh-into-a-machine-and-then-launch-an-interactive-command-line-program

Here is more info about the type of shells:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/what-is-the-difference-between-interactive-shells-login-shells-non-login-shell

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

Comment: Thanks, problem resolved by starting bash in interactive mode i.e. `ssh root@server "bash -i -c 'node /some-deploy-folder/do-something.js"`